# Where did the term "gumshoe" come from?

Tags: meaning

When someone refers to a detective or police officer, they sometimes use the term 'gumshoe'. Where did this term originate from?

Answer (score 3):

From [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/gumshoe):

> **gumshoe** (n.)
>   "plainclothes detective," 1906, from the rubber-soled shoes they wore (which were so called from 1863); from gum (n.1) + shoe (n.).

Comment: The connotation was that (prior to the internet and even telephones) detectives spent a lot of time walking about, "buttonholing" various people to collect information.  Rubber-soled shoes were easier on the feet.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah, without the shoes he'd turn into a *flatfoot*

Comment: @JimMack - Well, actually, he'd wear out too much shoe leather.